Use cloudfront distribution host as CNAME for root domain
I've created a Cloudfront distribution and got a address to put as CNAME.
The problem is that I can't set a CNAME  on a root Domain like mysite.com, just for subdomains.
My DNS records are from Azure, is there a way to solve this? How?
Use the ipv4 IP address from this cloud front distribution? Is there a chance that this IP changes over the time?
Thanks

While it may "work", it is not recommended to use an A record for your root domain with CloudFront. The IP addresses that your distribution currently resolves to may change without notice. Furthermore, these IP addresses may be different depending on where you're resolving from.
It's always best to use a proper AWS ALIAS record for root/apex domains with CloudFront distributions (not a DNS standard). For this to work, however, you do need to have your DNS hosted with AWS' Route 53 and not a third-party DNS such as Azure.
Some DNS systems such as Cloudflare do allow CNAME records on the apex domain (forced proxy though), others will have their own special record type for this, like ANAME, DNAME, etc. These are not DNS standards and may ultimately result in poor routing choice and thus subpar performance. Proxying with a third-party CDN may also be against the AWS Terms of Service.
Subdomains are much easier, CNAME records will work wonders, regardless of where they're hosted at.

Hi, thanks for the reply. I'll check the suggestions, as we have hard limitation to leave from Azure because the customer cost and other policies. We'll try to use a subdomain with CNAME and in the root domain do the redirect to www.
